# Calling method from Fragment in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a ViewPager with some Fragments inside. When creating each Fragment I call constructor where I pass name of this Fragment:

```
 public KwejkFragment(String tagName)
    {
        this.fragmentTag = tagName;
    }
```

In MainActivity ofcourse I create Adapter and ViewPager instance. Then I set listener of ViewPager:

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                Fragment fr = mAdapter.getItem(position);

                if(fr.equals(KwejkFragment.class))
                {
                    (KwejkFragment) fr.refresh(); //I'm trying to call method here for example showMeSomething() but it is unavailable.
                }

            }
```

And here I'd like to:

1)Get current visible Fragment in PagerView

2)Call specified method of this Fragment

How to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First make the method in the fragment to public and then use the following code

```
mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                Fragment fr = mAdapter.getItem(position);

                if(fr instanceOf KwejkFragment))
                {
                     fr.refresh(); 
                }

            }
```

Put the debugger in the refresh method and check whether it is getting called or not.

This code will work. Enjoy :)

Comment: Don't you get npe by calling getitem() ?

Comment: This is not called when by default first fragment is called. Any suggestions?

Comment: why have you created fragment manager object when you are not using it?

Comment: Hi friend, tnx for your answer. A little thing missed, you must cast fr fragment. Thanks again.
                if(fr instanceof KwejkFragment)) {
                     ((KwejkFragment) fr).refresh(); 
                }